# Trouble Injecting Aspect Class From External Project using Spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, aop

I apologize if this question has an answer already somewhere, I looked around and didn't see anything that I could use to my advantage.  I'm getting this exception when starting up my tomcat server inside of eclipse:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sample.aspects.SomeAspect
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1360)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1206)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:246)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1346)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:623)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1394)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:957)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:705)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4364)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

Here's the servlet.xml that I'm using

```
<bean id="someAspect"
    class="com.sample.aspects.SomeAspect" />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

The com.sample.aspects.SomeAspect is a class in an external project that I'm importing using the eclipse classpath and gradle.  I'm assuming I'm just doing something wrong with my classpath and telling Spring how to initialize my aspects, but I'm a bit lost as to how to do this correctly.  Any suggestions?  I'd really prefer to keep the aspect external to the web application, but I'm wondering if that's possible with Spring AOP.

If it helps, this is what I'm doing with the gradle project

```
dependencies{
...
    compile project(':sample-projectwithaspectsclasses')
}
```

The code for `com.sample.aspects.SomeAspect` is in sample-projectwithaspectsclasses

Comment: If you are still interested in an answer you might want to consider providing the community with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so as to enable them to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Good idea. I'll see about putting one together and dropping it on github.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined only the classpath dependency on your external project that is why your compilation is not failing, but you need this file at runtime you can manually add this jar into the lib folder of your web project or I think you can do this using eclipse in launch configurations and add runtime dependencies.

Comment: This may work - but what happens when I'm ready to deploy my project to an external tomcat server that I can't control the runtime dependencies on?

Comment: define the scope of dependency in pom like <scope>RUNTIME</scope>

Comment: I still haven't been able to determine what is causing this. But if I generate a .jar and then add it to my classpath I have no issues. I only see this if I have my .war project including the .jar protect in eclipse.